# Daily rep page does not show downvotes

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page, reputation-graph

The daily rep page summary does not seem to show posts from which downvotes have come.

[image: reputation page]

The profile dropdown shows the right rep, while the daily rep graph seems to ignore/not show posts which I have downvoted.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't like the lack of ability to see our downvotes conveniently, but this is actually probably by design. That page is public to anyone who visits your profile. If it documented who you had downvoted, then anyone would be able to see that information.

Likewise, since private data is viewable by moderators, I would expect that making downvotes cast private-only on that page would still end up rendering to moderators (who can also see your responses tab, as it were), which is information they normally do not have access to.

It does cause some differences between your displayed value in the drop down, and what the graph provides. But I think we'll have to wait for more of the Recent Activity overhaul before we'll get that functionality outside of `/recent`.